# Detect a UIVisualEffectView in Xcode UI Tests

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I have an app that blurs a portion of the screen until it is double-tapped, and I am having trouble verifying that action in the UITests.  The Accessibility Inspector does not seem to detect the UIVisualEffectView at all -- all UITableViewCells show up as "isHittable" and there is no element matching the Blur view.

There has to be a way to tell the difference between these two screens, right?

Here is a screenshot of before/after
[image: before]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try programmatically setting the isAccessibilityElement property to true on the UIVisualEffectView. Once you set it to true, it will be detected by the accessibility inspector and the isHittable property on your UITableViewCells will return the correct value.